# Big data. Store and analyze objects without using the RAM

Tags: r, matrix, bigdata, hierarchical-clustering

I'm trying to get a dissimilarity matrix with the funciton `beta.pair` of the package `betapart` from a database with 11000 rows x 6000 columns.

However, when I execute the function R gives me the error: "`cannot allocate a vector of size 10 GB`".

I'm using a Linux system with 65 GB of RAM, and R 64 bits, so I shouldn't have this limitation problem, and R should use all the available memory of the CPU, but it doesn't.

Do you know how can I use any package to store the dissimilarity matrix (e.g. bigmemory, ff) and later use it to perform an UPGMA analysis storing the result in the CPU and not in the RAM.

Exactly what I would like to do is:

```
library(betapart) 

data_base # Database with 6000 columns and 11000 rows
distance <- beta.pair (data_base, index.family="sorensen") # Object with the dissimilarity matrices. 

beta_similarity <- distance$beta.sim # Select one of the dissimilarity matrices provided by the function beta.pair

library(cluster) 
UPGMA<- agnes (beta_similarity ) # UPGMA analyses
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: What is the expected dimension of `distance`? You'll probably need to rewrite `beta.pair` to have it work in chunks. Btw., `cannot allocate a vector of size 10 GB` means that R has exhausted the available RAM and cannot allocate *another* 10 GB.

Comment: `distance` would contain different dissimilarity matrices of 11000x11000/2. Therefore later I select only one.
Regarding to the error message, I have been following the evolution of the RAM in the analysis and I could see that there was RAM available when I got the message. I don't know if it is possible that the computer has available RAM and R provides the message because it knows that there isn't enough space before to try it.

Comment: So, each of them has 60.5 million values. If you only need one of these matrices, you should calculate only one of them.

Comment: I know that I should select only one of them, but I don't know how to do it in R. Therefore I tried to get it manually in python, however my code wasn't optimized and spends to much time. 

In concret, I would like to get the Simpson pairwise dissimilarity provided by Baselga. (Andrés Baselga. Partitioning the turnover and nestedness components of beta diversity. Global Ecol. Biogeogr. 2010. 19, 134–143). Do you have any idea of how I could do it in R? Thanks